# How to enumerate Media Foundation Transforms on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

In my Windows Store application I want to make resampling with audio files.
It seems, what good solution for this problem is using Resampler object from Media Foundation Transforms. To get this object I should enumerate media transforms with function **MFTEnumEx**, as described here:
[Enumerating MFTs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/aa965254#enumerating_mfts).
But while certification I get such error: 
**API MFTEnumEx in mfplat.dll is not supported for this application type.**

Is there any other way to get avaiable on Windows 8 Transforms, or another way to resample audio files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that outside of native transforms which comes out of the box Windows store apps transforms (such as codecs) are sandboxed for your application.

If you setup a custom MFT with a traditional codec pack it won't be available to your windows store app. You'll have to package the MFT with your app and make it Activatable by WinRT (and also implement IMediaExtension). Remember that MediaExtensions are COM/WinRT mixes.

You have a list of supported formats here and I guess your best option is hardcoding it in your application :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx

Comment: What about examples of packaging MFT with application? Is it possible add standart transcoder to package?

In the table http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx I see WAV format with PCM. But how I should work with it?

Comment: You'll have to implement additional interfaces to make your MFT work with windows store Apps. There are samples there : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096

Comment: The Sink provided out of the box is limited to the following profiles : M4a,Mp3,Mp4,Wma,Wmv. But you can write a custom sink that will support Wav